# Como utilizar uma variável no controller do TextFormField?

Tags: flutter, input, controller

Estou com este problema:

Criei um CarouselSlider que contem um container com um TextFormField onde o usuário vai inserir alguns valores dependendo de qual container ele está visualizando.

```
CarouselSlider.builder(
            options: CarouselOptions(
              viewportFraction: 1,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.35
            ),
            itemCount: itemsBand.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index, int realIndex) {
              return Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Column(children: [
                  Text(
            "${itemsBand[index]['label']}",
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
            )
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: 90,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    validator: (value){
                      if(value!.isEmpty){
                        return 'Vazio';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    controller: _umVM,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "1X",
                    ),
                    inputFormatters: [maskTaxa],
                  ),
                ),
```

O problema é, todos esses imputs são independente e quando vou adicionar um valor em um campo, é adicionado nos outros. Isso se dá porque o controller está sendo o mesmo em todos os builds do carousel.
Para resolver esse problema, preciso criar uma outra variável controller e informar ao flutter que ele utilize diferentes variáveis no controller.

Gostaria de fazer isso no controller do TextFormField:

```
TextFormField(
                    validator: (value){
                      if(value!.isEmpty){
                        return 'Vazio';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    controller: ${variável_dos_controllers[index]},
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "1X",
                    ),
                    inputFormatters: [maskTaxa],
                  ),
```

Assim, eu resolveria meu problema mas o controller não aceita esse tipo de implementação. Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Oi Lucas! Bem vindo ao site. Me parece que você mesmo deu a resposta para o seu problema, só está com dificuldades de implementar. O que você chamou de ```variável_dos_controllers``` deveria ficar fora do ```CarouselSlider.builder.```. Existe algo que impeça isso? Como não podemos ver aonde esse slider está inserido, fica difícil entender completamente sua pergunta. Então se puder, seria legal editar sua pergunta e mostrar onde o carrossel está inserido. Um exemplo mínimo que desse para rodar aumentaria também bastante as chances de uma resposta. Valeu e boa sorte!

Answer (score -2):

Tive soluções até que simples para resolver esse problema e vou auxiliar aos que possam passar pela mesma dúvida...

Eu estava chamando da forma clássica:

```
controller: controller: ${variável_dos_controllers[index]},
```

A minha conclusão é somente você fazer isso:

```
controller: variável_dos_controllers[index],
```

Que também funciona!